# Insert counter after regex match in string

Tags: regex, r, perl

### Insert counter after match in string

I'm  trying to insert a count-suffix after each match in a string.

**For example:** Inserting a number after each matched "o" in the following string:

```
"The Apollo program was conceived early in 1960"
```

Would look like:

```
"The Apo1llo2 pro3gram was co4nceived early in 1960"
```

I guess I should use `gsub` maybe with `perl = TRUE`, but don't know how.

```
string <- "The Apollo program was conceived early in 1960"

gsub( x = string, pattern = "(o)", replacement = "\\1 $count", perl = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option that uses the powerful combination of `gregexpr`, `regmatches`, and `regmatches<-`:

```
x <- c("The Apollo program was conceived early in 1960",
       "The International Space Station was launched in 1998")

m <- gregexpr("(?<=o)", x, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(x,m) <- lapply(regmatches(x,m), seq_along)

x
# [1] "The Apo1llo2 pro3gram was co4nceived early in 1960"    
# [2] "The Internatio1nal Space Statio2n was launched in 1998"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach:

```
x <- "The Apollo program was conceived early in 1960"

library(stringi)  ## or
pacman::p_load(stringi)  ## to load and install if not found

do.call(sprintf, c(list(gsub("o", "o%s", x)), seq_len(stri_count_regex(x, "o"))))

## [1] "The Apo1llo2 pro3gram was co4nceived early in 1960"
```

Or more succinctly:

```
pacman::p_load(qdapRegex, stringi)
S(gsub("o", "o%s", x), 1:stri_count_regex(x, "o"))
```

Note: I maintain the **pacman** and **qdapRegex** packages.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility using `gsubfn`, on the `x` from @Josh O'Brien.

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) paste0(x, count))
gsubfn("o", p, x)

# [1] "The Apo1llo2 pro3gram was co4nceived early in 1960"    
# [2] "The Internatio1nal Space Statio2n was launched in 1998"
```

For further reading, please see the nice [**`gsubfn` vignette**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this question as Perl, here's a Perl solution.

```
$string = "The Apollo program was conceived early in 1960";
$string =~ s/o/o . ++$i/eg;
say $string;
```